# I want to print a formatted array in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, format

I haven't been able to find any questions similar to my situation so I hope I'm not missing something.

I have an array of strings. I want to print every 3 strings on their own line with commas and spacing.

Here is my method:

```
public static void Modify(String stringSearch)
{
    ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        File file = new File("Temp.txt");
        input = new Scanner(file);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (input.hasNext()) {
        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            String firstName = input.next();
            String lastName = input.next();
            String phoneNumber = input.next();

            if ((Objects.equals(firstName, stringSearch)) || (Objects.equals(lastName, stringSearch)) || (Objects.equals(phoneNumber, stringSearch))) {

                records.add(firstName);
                records.add(lastName);
                records.add(phoneNumber);
            }
        } // end while
    }
    int size;
    size = (records.size()) / 3;
    System.out.printf("Found %d records:%n", size);

    String[] Array = records.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (int s = 0; s < Array.length; s++) {
        System.out.printf("%s", Array[s]);
    }
}
```

I am converting an arrayList to a string array in order to try and format it. I'm very new to java and am working on a project in a time crunch.

I need it to print exactly like this:

Found 2 records:

```
1) Garcia,     John      505-338-2567
2) John,       Joseph    212-780-3342
```

It is printing like this:

Found 2 records:

```
GarciaJohn505-338-2567JohnJoseph212-780-3342
```

Comment: What is not working? What don't you understand? What is the question?

Comment: I edited my post. I need to format the output into a numbered list with commas and spacing!

Answer (score 0):

Java is an Object-Oriented language, and you should use it.

Create a class representing your `Person`, with `firstName`, `lastName`, and `phoneNumber` as *fields*.

Then you create a `List<Person>` with 2 objects in it, and write a method for printing that list. The `System.out.printf()` you're already using can help output values in columns like you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create you own data-structure, with a `toString()` method that suits your needs.

Something like:

```
public class PersonalCustomerData {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNumber;


...


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return lastName + "," + " " + firstName + " " + phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

And, as @Andreas mentioned in his answer, you also need a `Collection<PersonalCustomerData>`, that when you iterate over it, you print your fully formatted output:

```
private Collection<PersonalCustomerData> col;

// init the collection + do stuff...

public void printCustomerData() {
    int lineNumber = 0;

    for(PersonalCustomerData pcd : col) {
        lineNumber++;

        System.out.println(lineNumber + ")" + " " + pcd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `object` to contain your values and stick with your plan of doing. you can use this code to print it with format.

Replace this:

```
     String[] Array = records.toArray(new String[0]);
     for (int s = 0; s < Array.length; s++) {
         System.out.printf("%s", Array[s]);
     }
```

to this:

```
    int numberOfLine = 1; // Counter of words per line
    String[] Array = records.toArray(new String[0]);
    for(String str : Array) {
        String strSperator = "";
        switch (numberOfLine) {
        case 1:
            strSperator = ",    ";
            numberOfLine++;
            break;
        case 2:
            strSperator = "     ";
            numberOfLine++;
            break;
        case 3:
            strSperator = "\n";
            numberOfLine = 1;
            break;
        }
        System.out.printf("%s%s",str,strSperator);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
    for (int s = 0; s < Array.length; s++) {
    System.out.printf("%s", Array[s]);`
```

to something like this. I didn't test out the code so there might be small typos or what not. I think this will do what you want.

As Andreas said, it would be better if you make a person class. It will look more organized and probably easier to understand.

```
int counter = 1;
System.out.print(records.get(0) + ",\t")
while (counter !=records.size())
{
if(counter %3 ==0)
System.out.println(records.get(counter));
else if(counter% 3== 1)
System.out.print(records.get(counter) + ",\t");
else
System.out.print(records.get(counter)+ "\t");
counter ++;
}
```

Since your first element will always be first name , 2nd element will be last name and 3rd element is the phone number, I print the first one initially then the modding and the while loop should handle everything I believe.